# Getting libstdc++-v3/python

Tags: c++, python, svn, download, gdb

I am trying to download libstdc++-v3/python to enable pretty printing of stl containers. However, my provider  returns: **svn: Unknown hostname 'gcc.gnu.org'** error. This is the command:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
```

**Is there an alternative way to get this package?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try http:// instead of svn://
that would be :
svn co http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python

Comment: same problem:  svn: PROPFIND request failed  on svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python 

 svn: PROPFIND of  /svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python: Could not resolve hostname 'gcc.gnu.org': Host not found (http://gcc.gnu.org))

Comment: do you have dns problems? on my machine the svn:// adress isn't working but the http one is working just fine. Maybe you're behind a proxy?

Comment: I think I am behind proxy... I will try it externally.

Comment: Is there a way to get it without svn -- say by way of a regular download?

Comment: well, you can point your browser to http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python/

Answer (score 2):

They appear to be available from here now:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it worked with

https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python/